# Sum of sum totals

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate

I'm looking to get a sum of sum using db2.  I'm getting a -204 error obviously because I'm trying to calculate an aggregate using an alias.  I'm not sure how to approach this and would appreciate some help.

```
SELECT 
    DA.AMOUNT,
    cast(sum(cast(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT as real)) as integer) as time_used,
    (DA.AMOUNT - sum(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)) as time_to_use,
    concat(((sum(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)/DA.AMOUNT)*100),'%') AS Percentage_used,
    **sum(time_used)/SUM(DA.AMOUNT) AS Total_Percentage_Used**    

    FROM FACT_Table as FAT
        RIGHT DIM_AWARD DA ON FAT.DIM_ID = DA.DIM_ID
        group by DA.AMOUNT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to substitute back in the expression for the amount:

```
SELECT DA.AMOUNT,
       cast(sum(cast(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT as real)) as integer) as time_used,
       (DA.AMOUNT - sum(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)) as time_to_use,
       concat(((sum(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)/DA.AMOUNT)*100),'%') AS Percentage_used,
       cast(sum(cast(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT as real)) as integer)/DA.AMOUNT AS Total_Percentage_Used  
FROM FACT_Table as FAT
     RIGHT DIM_AWARD DA ON FAT.DIM_ID = DA.DIM_ID
group by DA.AMOUNT;
```

Because you have `DA.AMOUNT` in the `group by`, you don't need it to wrap it in `sum()`.

If you are concerned about the `sum()` being `NULL`, then use `coalesce()`:
    coalesce(cast(sum(cast(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT as real)) as integer), 0.0) / DA.AMOUNT AS Total_Percentage_Used

Comment: Thanks for the response Gordon.  How do you handle null values?  cast(sum(cast(isnull(FAT.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT as real), "0") as integer)/DA.AMOUNT AS Total_Percentage_Used?

Comment: You don't need to worry about the nulls, they won't affect your sum(). Aggregate functions ignore nulls, so there's no point in coalescing them to a zero, which also would have no effect.